# How to convert one format of json into another using python?

Tags: python, json

I Want to convert json1 into json2 with minimal looping in Python because there are many records like below.

JSON1:

```
{
"1-5":[
{
"NAME": "A",
"AGE": "1"
},

{
"NAME": "A",
"AGE": "2"
},
{
"NAME": "B",
"AGE": "3"
}
],

"6-10":[
{
"NAME": "x",
"AGE": "6"
},

{
"NAME": "y",
"AGE": "6"
},
{
"NAME": "z",
"AGE": "10"
}
]
}
```

---

JSON2:

```
{
"1": [
{
"NAME": "A",
"AGE": "1"
}
],

"2": [
{
"NAME": "A",
"AGE": "2"
},
{
"NAME": "B",
"AGE": "2"
}

],

"3": [
{
"NAME": "B",
"AGE": "1"
}
],
...
}
```

Is there any way to do like this, Could anyone help me with this?

**Note** Extra info for this question to be submitted.

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format. It is easy for humans to read and write. It is easy for machines to parse and generate. It is based on a subset of the JavaScript Programming Language Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition - December 1999.

Comment: Can u share the implementation you have tried, to better aid the community to help you

Comment: Also, this looks like some question copied from somewhere

Comment: In that case, could you please kindly share that question which you think I copied?

Comment: Is it an assignment/homework/test? Please edit your code into your question.

Comment: `JSON` means data converted to string which you can save to file or send by network. But to work with data you have to convert `JSON` to normal python structure (list or dict) using `json.loads()`, next change data in this structure, and finally convert it back to JSON using `json.dumps()`

Comment: you're going to have to give us your rules for changing the structure here, it llooks like the same structure just with items grouped by age?

Comment: @Tenacious B. No other rules. As you said, items grouped by age. That's it

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself? StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service - please edit your attempt into your question.